Is there a way to render a conditional div faster so that when the condition is met the container does not grow as it is opened?
I am trying to render a modal that either opens with a carousel of different images or opens with a single static image. I am using useState to track whether that condition is met within a useEffect hook.
as laid out here:
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isModalOpen) {
      if (focusItem?.hasDetail) {
        var arr: string[] = focusItem?.detailPicture?.split(";");
        arr?.unshift(focusItem?.pictureLnk);
        setDetail(arr);
        setHasDetail(true);
      }
    }
  }, [isModalOpen, hasDetail]);

I have tried keeping the layout the same i.e. same height and conditionally rendered component and it works as it assumes the default of not containing the carousel with preview images. However, my goal is to have it render at the same speed. I'm guessing my logic is off and there is a better way to conditionally render these differences.
Here is how I am conditionally rendering the components:
 <div className="modalCont">
                        {hasDetail ? (
                          <div className="carouselModalImgWrap">
                            <div className="carouselArrwContLeft">
                              <Left
                                className={`carouselArrw ${carouselIndex == 0 ? "arrwDisabled" : ""}`}
                                onClick={arrowDecrement}
                              />
                            </div>
                            <div className="carouselImgCont">
                              {detail?.map((url, i) => {
                                return (
                                  <div
                                  key={url}
                                    className="carouselImgFit"
                                    style={{
                                      translate: `${-100 * carouselIndex}%`,
                                      transition: `300ms translate ease-in-out`,
                                    }}
                                  >
                                    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                                      <img 
                                        className={`modalImg ${carouselIndex == i ? "" : "hideModalImg"}`}
                                        key={url}
                                        src={url}
                                      />
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                );
                              })}
                            </div>
                            <div className={`carouselImgPrvwWrap ${hasDetail ? "hasWrap" : "nowWrap"}`}>
                              {detail?.map((url, i) => {
                                return (
                                  <div className={`carouselImgPrvCont ${carouselIndex == i ? "carouselImgPrevActive": ""}`}>
                                    <img key={url} src={url} className="carouselImgPrv"/>
                                  </div>
                                );
                              })}
                            </div>
                            <div className="carouselArrwContRight">
                              <Right
                                className={`carouselArrw ${carouselIndex == detail?.length - 1 ? "arrwDisabled" : ""}`}
                                onClick={arrowIncrement}
                              />
                            </div>
                            
                          </div>
                        ) : (
                          <div className="modalImgWrap">
                            <div className="modalImgCont">
                              <img
                                className="modalImg"
                                loading="lazy"
                                src={focusItem && focusItem.pictureLnk}
                              />
                            </div>
                            <div className={`carouselImgPrvwWrap ${hasDetail ? "hasWrap" : "nowWrap"}`}>
                           
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        )}

Where I am having trouble is at this point:
<div className={`carouselImgPrvwWrap ${hasDetail ? "hasWrap" : "nowWrap"}`}>
                              {detail?.map((url, i) => {
                                return (
                                  <div className={`carouselImgPrvCont ${carouselIndex == i ? "carouselImgPrevActive": ""}`}>
                                    <img key={url} src={url} className="carouselImgPrv"/>
                                  </div>
                                );
                              })}

The difference being that if it contains a detail, the div is 50px, otherwise it is 0px. I had originally tried omitting the div entirely if there is no detail, but the result is the same.
Please let me know if there is a better way of doing this, or I am going down the wrong path...

At this case, It's better to use useLayoutEffect instead of useEffect
The main difference between them is: useLayoutEffect is executed before rendering, while useEffect is running after.
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (isModalOpen) {
      if (focusItem?.hasDetail) {
        var arr: string[] = focusItem?.detailPicture?.split(";");
        arr?.unshift(focusItem?.pictureLnk);
        setDetail(arr);
        setHasDetail(true);
      }
    }
  }, [isModalOpen, hasDetail]);

https://react.dev/reference/react/useLayoutEffect
This answer is according to what is available in the question. More context of the component would make difference.
You might not need an effect at all. If the effect is only responsible for detecting whether hasDetail or not. You can do something like this:
const hasDetail = isModalOpen && focusItem?.hasDetail

